# Echoing post meta in divs

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

Argh, this code is not pulling through my custom meta.

```
<?php 
$my_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_my_meta', true);
if (!empty($post_meta)) {
?>
<div class='client-testimonial'><?php echo $my_meta['testimonial']; ?></div>
<div class='client-name'><?php echo $my_meta['name']; ?></div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

But the one below works, the only reason I am not using it is because it still shows the speach marks and dash when the fields are left empty in the admin panel

```
        <?php 
$my_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_my_meta', true);
echo "<div class='client-testimonial'>". "'".$my_meta['testimonial']."'". "</div>";
echo "<div class='client-name'>". "-" .$my_meta['name']."</div>";
?>
```

Please help me on why the first code is not echoing the info. I am at the end of my tether!

Comment: try `if (!empty($my_meta))` instead of `if (!empty($post_meta))`

Answer (score 0):

You're checking if `$post_meta` is not empty, you don't have a variable named `$post_meta`

Change:

```
if (!empty($post_meta))
```

to

```
if (!empty($my_meta))
```

Answer (score 0):

i think u have checked wrong variable.

```
<?php 
    $my_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_my_meta', true);

    if (isset($my_meta) && !empty($my_meta)) {
    ?>
    <div class='client-testimonial'><?php echo $my_meta['testimonial']; ?></div>
    <div class='client-name'><?php echo $my_meta['name']; ?></div>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
```